# Benchmark an stochastic constrain solver

Tags: optimization, constrained-optimization

I wrote a small simulated annealing library in C++. Right now is just a few classes, a toy project I want to use to test some ideas. But before I move on I want to be sure that it works. Meaning, that if I give it a difficult problem it will work. I won't be fast, or efficient, or whatever. I just want to be sure it works.

I've tried simple examples, but I would like to benchmark it. Does anybody know of a set of problems to solve? Nonlinear and constrained.

Comment: I found this: (If I get no better options in a few days I'll put that as an answer) http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~neum/glopt/test.html#test_constr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I could find is  this:

http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~neum/glopt/test.html#test_constr

it has a paper with different functions and results. But no code that I could use.